# Как в Ubuntu управлять кулером?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Вопрос в следующем, стоит  Ubuntu как 2-я система. Скажите, есть ли утилита или в терминале функция через которую можно управлять кулером на ЦП?
Fancontrol - не работает, выдаёт-типа не могу что-то найти и т.п....
У меня ноутбук 73Titan и мне не хочется убить машину:(
Тонны текста перелопачены в молоко!
Может кто знает, как сделать управления кулером?

Comment: ман по кулеру прочитан?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_speed_control_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: PinkTux, прочитан,мне нужно УПРАВЛЕНИЕ, а не сбавка оборотов, понимаете о чём я??вел  команду он на средних,вёл другую от поднялся до 2000 оборотов...вот что мне нужно.делала это ПОФИГ ему...:\

Comment: Никто тебе так не скажет, нет единого решения, там много контекста, такие вещи нужно вытеснять в диалоге, с этим вопросом тебе скорее помогут на линуксовом форуме как например linux.org.ru, а так могу скзать что обычно если и можно управлять куллером, то самый низкоуровневый способ это через виртуальную fs /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/ и там нужно найти файлы pwm* и пытаться туда что-то свое записать.